# Не регистрируется slash команда discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

Мне нужно сделать slash команду в discord.py, но саму команду у меня не регистрирует, и при этом никакой ошибки нету. Заранее спасибо!

````
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import os

token = 'ТОКЕН'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '*', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.tree.sync()

class MyModal(discord.ui.Modal, title = 'Title'):
    Test_one = discord.ui.TextInput(label = 'label', placeholder = 'placeholder', required = False, max_length = 100, min_length = 5, style = discord.TextStyle.short)

@client.tree.command(name = 'слеш-команда', description = 'Описание')
async def command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_modal(MyModal())

client.run(token)```
````